# QVector of QStrings, how to join?

Tags: qt, qvector, qstringlist

Due to several reasons, e.g. the `mid` method, I would prefer to use a `QVector<QString>` over `QStringList`.
The only downside I face is that I also have to join the elements from time to time to a single QString.

In QStringlist that is easy, you can simply use `join(',')`, but how to do that when using a `QVector<QString>` without writing a dedicated function? Is there something like a `.map()` method?

Comment: That's not possible without a couple lines of code each time you need it. I don't know your Qt version (idk if it changed over time) but `.mid()` is present for `QStringList` in Qt5(15.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your "several reasons" were supposed to be; at the very least the `mid` method exists for `QStringList` in all the supported version of Qt.

More details:

- Qt5:
  Qt 5.15 LTS has a `mid` method for `QStringList`, is the last supported version of Qt5, and **goes out of standard support by end of May 2023**, out of subscribers' support in 2025.
- Qt6:
  `QVector` and `QList` are now the exact same type. By extension, a `QStringList` is a `QVector<QString>`.

Conclusion: your question will not make sense in just 3 months (27 months if you are a subscriber) and if just talking about a `mid` method, it was in fact already present.

Comment: you are right and since that is the main reason I will then go with QStringList. Thanks!